# Using Revision Variable in Docker Build Step

Tags: docker, azure-devops

Trying to use the `$(Rev:.r)` variable in my docker build steps (version 1.*) for tagging and it doesn't seem to work. I always get

> 2019-01-14T21:42:24.4149933Z ##[error]invalid argument
>   "wp/imagename:0.6$(rev:.r)" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference
>   format 2019-01-14T21:42:24.4160700Z ##[error]See 'docker build
>   --help'. 2019-01-14T21:42:24.4274219Z ##[error]/usr/bin/docker failed with return code: 125

No variable substitution seems to be happening and it looks like it's running it through with the Qualify image name option and lower-casing the R. Can anyone else use the `$(Rev:.r)` variable?

Doesn't matter where I try using that variable, i can use it in the Image Name option or the Arguments option and it gives me the same error.

```
-t wp/imagename:0.6$(Rev:.r)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've only been able to get it to be recognized in the Build number format section under options.

If you are using this like a build number, why not just set the build number there instead and then reference using $(Build.BuildNumber)?

Answer (score 3):

You can't get just "the revision number" without parsing, it is not stored as a separate field somewhere. The `$(Rev:.r)` portion instructs Azure DevOps to come up with the first number that makes the build number unique (and, in that specific example, put a dot in front of it). Only the final build number is available.

At workaround, add a the `$(Rev:.r)` in the end of your build number (if it not there). add a PowerShell script task (you can do it inline PowerShell) before the Docker task and put this code:

```
$buildNumber = $Env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER
$revision= $buildNumber.Substring($buildNumber.LastIndexOf('.') + 1)
Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=revision;]$revision")
```

In your docker use the `$revision` variable:

```
-t wp/imagename:0.6$(revision)
```